# Angular material date picker not displaying current date

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I have an application that uses Angular material date picker. I am using this application in India. But when this application is used in Pennsylvania the current date is not displayed. How can I display the current date when the same application is used in Pennsylvania?

*app.module.ts*

```
 import {MatDatepickerModule} 
 from 
'@angular/material/datepicker'

import {MatNativeDateModule} 
 from 
'@angular/material/core'
 import {DatePipe} from 
'@angular/common';

 @NgModule({
imports: 
[MatDatepickerModule, 
 MatNativeDateModule ];
 providers: [DatePipe]
 })
```

*component.html*

```
 <mat-date-range-input 
 [rangepicker]="picker">
  <input matStartDate 
   placeholder="start date" 
   formControlName="startDate">
   <input matEndDate 
   placeholder="end date" 
   formControlName="endDate">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker 
 disabled="false"></mat-date- 
 range-picker>
```